# In C#, how can I access a fileshare on a domain from outside a domain?

Tags: c#, file, active-directory

I've got a webserver where people upload files. What I need to do is take those files and write them to a file share on the Active Directory domain. The problem -- the webserver is not on the domain.

So, how is the best way to do this? I would have thought this would be easy, something along the lines of create a connection with some credentials and do it. But apparently not. The closest I've found is Impersonation with `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate`, but everything I've read says that is a bad idea in a production environment.

Any ideas? I'm working on a solution that FTPs the files, but that's unsatisfying too, and a fallback plan.

I'm using c# and .net 4.0 in (obviously) a windows environment.

**Edit:** I should point out that I can't run servers (or services) that access the outside on that domain. The FTPing is a temporary workaround.

Comment: The only problem with Impersonate is if you let the user credentials leak outside of the context where they're supposed to be used, which can *easily* happen if an exception is thrown while impersonating.  Use a subprocess to perform the impersonation, the process boundary will provide a secure wall preventing credentials from leaking across.

Comment: @Ben Voigt That's an interesting point. If I end up having to do Impersonate (and I may, the ftp is a temporary measure) I'll definately do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would have another program probably a Windows service pick the files from the web service file location and move them to the active directory directory. I would probably have this process execute from the location where they are being copied to. Make them available in a share on the web server visible only to the process's user and admins.

Comment: I'd prefer something a little less complicated. And also that doesn't have another moving part to it like running a windows service.

Comment: I like this option because it prevents issues in accessing the share from affecting the web app.  If the service has a problem moving the file (transitory network issues, file server down, whatever), it can just try again later.

Comment: Ok, in the interests of keeping my options open, let's pursue this for a second. Is there a service like this already available, or are you talking about making a program and running it as a windows service?

Comment: Yeah, while you might be able to find or purchase a product that does just that, I envision a very simple service that uses FileSystemWatcher to watch for new files and then moves the files to your new location. If you write it with Topshelf (http://code.google.com/p/topshelf) it will run/test as a console application and run/installed as a service.

Comment: @kenny -- thanks. I'll keep writing a `FileSystemWatcher` open as an option. Unfortunately, trying to do this thing looks like it's going to be more complicated than I'd hoped. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that an FTP solution is better than using a Windows Share; however, I would think a web service of some type would be the best option for an inter-domain file exchange. That said, if you've got it working with `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate` -- why not use it? What context did you read that it was a bad idea?

Comment: I don't have it working with Impersonate, that's just an option I found on the internet. The problem with it is the potential to leak the credentials; also, I believe it can have issues since the entire program then gets masked as the identity it's impersonating. What I'd like is to simply access the share, and nothing more.

Comment: @Patches: I'm pretty sure impersonation is per-thread... but you can still run into huge trouble if that thread is a thread pool worker thread, since you have little control over how long it will live or what code it might run in the future, or even whether that code is part of your AppDomain.  In a thread you control, the problem is less, but I still say the best is an entirely separate helper process.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way that you can map this file share as Network Driver. If you can do that, you don't need to manager Security and will be super easy to access these files as if they are local.

Comment: Ok. Not to be a total n00b, but how do I go about doing that from within my c# class, or, from in my asp.net project?

Comment: Wow, that's worse than `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate`.  Mapped drives are accessible to every program running under the web service user, while `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate` is at least restricted to a single thread.

Comment: yea, can't do that then. I certainly can't go in the less secure direction from `Impersonate`.